# How to Enable IPtables TRACE Target on Debian Squeeze (6)

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, logging, log-files

I am trying to use the TRACE target of IPtables but I can't seem to get any trace information logged. I want to use what is described here:
[Debugger for Iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/122157/debugger-for-iptables).

From the iptables man for TRACE:

> ```
>    This target marks packes so that the kernel will log every  rule  which
>    match  the  packets  as  those traverse the tables, chains, rules. (The
>    ipt_LOG or ip6t_LOG module is required for the  logging.)  The  packets
>    are   logged   with   the   string   prefix:  "TRACE:  tablename:chain-
>    name:type:rulenum " where type can be "rule" for plain  rule,  "return"
>    for  implicit  rule at the end of a user defined chain and "policy" for
>    the policy of the built in chains.
>    It can only be used in the raw table.
> ```

I use the following rule: `iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -j TRACE` but nothing is appended either in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/kern.log!

Is there another step missing? Am I looking in the wrong place?

#### edit

Even though I can't find log entries, the TRACE target seems to be set up correctly since the packet counters get incremented:

```
# iptables -L -v -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 193 packets, 63701 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  193 63701 TRACE      tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 178 packets, 65277 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### edit 2

The rule `iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -j LOG` *does* print packet information to /var/log/syslog... Why doesn't TRACE work?

Comment: just stumpled upon a python program (which is also called iptables-trace :).
When started it adds a TRACE rule with specified conditions into running iptables, parses and display formatted output for resulting TRACE output until the program is stopped (which removes the TRACE rule from iptables).
Will try this soon...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run:

```
modprobe ipt_LOG
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The logs are available in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/kern.log

Answer (score 18):

Seems like (i.e. works for me) with new kernel this is needed (for IPv4):

```
modprobe nf_log_ipv4
sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4
```

credits:

- https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=54411
- upvoting other answers as they gave me important hints

Comment: This was the one that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-21-generic)

Comment: Unfortunately the `modinfo nf_log_ipv4` description just says: "Netfilter IPv4 packet logging". Some description could improve the answer: What does the sysctl do exactly?

Comment: `sysctl: setting key "net.netfilter.nf_log.2": No such file or directory` is what I get

Answer (score 8):

I found that I needed to perform both of the previous answers, in this order:

```
sudo modprobe ipt_LOG
sudo sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=ipt_LOG
```

Here are a couple of things that I discovered along the way.

You can get a list of valid loggers (along with the currently selected logger) with the following:

```
cat /proc/net/netfilter/nf_log
```

The numbers here represent the protocol family numbers, as defined in `/usr/include/bits/socket.h`.  2 is `AF_INET` (that's IPv4), and 10 is `AF_INET6` (IPv6).

Answer (score 7):

The question specifically ask for debian squeeze so this answer is not strictly relevant, but since this is the top result for "iptables TRACE", I want to clarify a little.

Those answers are all correct, but for modern systems, most likely you're actually using iptables-nft, check `iptables -V`, simply speaking your userspace program acts very much like real iptables but under the hood it's nftables in the kernel, in that case ipt_LOG and stuff mentioned in other answers(and two tutorials about this subject I found) won't work, instead you may check trace logs using a userspace program `xtables-monitor --trace`, source:
https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDX

Further reading from redhat about iptables-nft:
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/08/18/iptables-the-two-variants-and-their-relationship-with-nftables

Comment: This definitely needs more upvotes, this worked with ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me `sudo sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=ipt_LOG`