# How to simulate a source IP to test which iptables rules are/aren't firing?

Tags: iptables, firewall, unix

We have a fairly complicated iptables/ipchains configuration, which is generated by [APF](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/). Traffic to port 80 should be blocked, but our Apache logs show that someone was able to probe for web pages:

```
[Sun Feb 03 13:08:45 2013] [error] [client 50.57.125.169] File does not exist:     /var/www/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)
[Sun Feb 03 13:08:45 2013] [error] [client 50.57.125.169] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Sun Feb 03 13:08:45 2013] [error] [client 50.57.125.169] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Is there a way to simulate a source IP in iptables to debug why packet from `50.57.125.169` didn't get blocked? The `-C | --check` option seems to only report whether there exists a rule that explicitly matches the IP, but what I'd like to do is (*pseudocode*)

```
myserver% iptables --test --source_ip=50.57.125.169 --dest_port=80
Rule #17 matches (ALLOW)    // i.e. this would be the rule that matches
```

Is there a way to do this?

[edit]
One partial solution was to enable `TRACE` debugging on iptables (cf. https://serverfault.com/a/126078/67472) and use `hping3` (thanks Trent) which can spoof a source IP. However, the results are not showing up when the test is run from a different server, and when run from the same server, it goes over the Loopback interface.

Comment: Check about ip spoofing for your operating system

Comment: There is no actual Rule #17. That was the "pseudocode" (i.e. my wishlist output) of the command I'm looking for. I have edited the question to make it more clear that "Rule 17" is fiction.

Comment: Wow... wonder why this question closed as not a real question.  It's really obvious what's being asked and IMO is a real question.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, that's kind of you. I couldn't figure out why either. Unfortunately, I don't have enough Karma to reopen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you just use hping to simulate the source IP address of the traffic and then check to see if the traffic is still getting through?  Probably not quite what you are looking for but you could do something like

```
hping3 --syn --destport 80 --count 3 -a test.ip.address webserver.ip.address
```

Comment: Good idea. I thought using the `-a` option to spoof the source port will make me not get replies; how would it show up if the port was allowed versus blocked?

Comment: you would need to look at you application logs to see if the connection was reaching your application

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scapy` to spoof your IP address.

Comment: Looks like a possibility, but an example spoofing the source IP would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am not directly addressing the question you asked, but having used APF for quite some time, I could advise you on how to block the IP, in case you used a different approach.

example:to block port 80 for the host 1.2.3.4-add the following line  `/etc/apf/deny_hosts.rules`

```
    tcp:in:d=80:s=1.2.3.4
```

In addition to this, in stead of going through the hassle of spoofing source IP, why not try to block the IP address of some client computer under your own control and try to connect from it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Daniel. I have many of such rules in place, the issue is I'm trying to figure out why someone else snuck through. I'll look into the deny rules again to be sure.